# Linear Feedback Shift Registers on FPGA's

Tags: fpga, programmable-logic, hdl

I want to put 256 linear feedback shift registers on a FPGA and each LFSR will have just two tap positions for the XNOR feedback and each register is 63 cells . I don't care if the LFSR'S are not maximal length. The catch is I want the tap positions for all these shift registers to be easily reconfigurable. How difficult/easy is it to do this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a whole lot more information as to what you have tried so far, what you are struggling with, what languages you are familiar with (VHDL? Verilog?), what FPGA you are targeting. Otherwise you will quickly find the question gets closed for being too broad.

Comment: Xilinx LUTs in shift register mode can be used with dynamic shift width. Please extend your question as Tom asked.

Comment: How fast do you need them clocked?  Are they all running off the same clock?

Comment: Clocking at 25Mhz and they are all running off the same clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Xilinx FPGAs, the LUTs can be configured as 32-bit shift registers (SRL32), each with one adjustable tap.  What I would recommend is using 6 of these 32-bit shift registers as three 63-bit registers in parallel, one fixed at 63 bits and the other two for the variable taps.  With a bit of additional logic it should be possible to implement this with fewer registers, though there could be some disruption when changing the tap selection under certain conditions.

If you aren't using Xilinx FPGAs, then it might be advisable to look at the programming manuals to figure out what sort of shift register features are supported.  It is possible to make variable length shift registers with large MUXes, though this could consume a lot of logic resources.  Dual-port RAMs are another option, especially for longer shift registers or for multiple parallel shift registers with identical taps.  Depending on the architectural features of the FPGAs and your design constraints, one option may make more sense than the others.

Another consideration is constraints on how the shift register taps are changed.  If you need to change the taps on-the-fly without disturbing the contents of the shift registers, this could limit what architectures you can use and some of the optimizations you might be able to make.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved "easily" - that is, in a straightforward manner - but it will suck up considerable resources and cut down maximum frequency. What you do is to feed each input to the XNOR gate from a 256:1 multiplexer, with each register stage feeding one input to each of the two muxes. A 256-bit mux will have several levels of gates, so the total propagation through the mux will be relatively slow. Since I don't know your desired clock rate, I can't predict if this will be a problem.

Each mux will require an 8-bit control byte, and this can be done in various ways, the most straightforward being a total of 16 parallel inputs. Or you can have 8 inputs feeding 2 8-bit registers with 2 clocks (or a single clock and an enable address). Or you can have a pair of serial inputs feeding 8-bit shift registers. Or, or, or, etc. Depends on your taste in control interfaces. If you really want to get creative you can use an Ethernet/TCPIP link. Or an RS232 interface.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean runtime configurable, because compile time configurable would be trivial with generics.

For runtime configuration you'll have to use the LUTs as dual port rams.  64-bits of RAM will give you a look up table for 6 of your 256 bits.  (Use 6 taps as the address).  You would program the look up table to just feed one of the 6 bits through if that one is a a tap that you picked.  (Zero if there are no taps in the 6 bits). Then you'll have to combine the results of all of the rams with XOR and invert to get the desired XNOR.  The speed will likely be limited by the XOR combining tree of 256/6 lookups.